# Delegate call can not update already opened report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, delegates

I am creating c# application. I have two forms let say MainForm and ReportForm. I opened both forms side by side. When some data is saved into database on mainform, i want to show it automatically on reportform. I'm using delegates and delegate call the report method but the crystal report does not update report. There is a button of preview. Clicking that button shows the report correctly with updated changes.

My Mainform code is

```
    EndSale();
    if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Reports.FullSaleReport>().Count() == 1)
                {
                    Reports.FullSaleReport saleReport = (Reports.FullSaleReport)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Reports.FullSaleReport));
                    ShowSaleReport sale = new ShowSaleReport(saleReport.ShowReport);
                    sale("%", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString());
                }
```

My reportform code is

```
public void ShowReport(string cbx, string FromDate, string ToDate)
    {
        String Query = "Select a.Id, a.CustomerName, Convert(varchar(12), a.SaleDate, 106) as 'SaleDate', d.ProductName + ISNULL(' ' + d.Potency, '') + ' ' + e.Description as 'Product', b.ProductQuantity, b.ProductUnitPrice, Convert(decimal(16, 2), b.ProductTotalPrice) as 'TotalPrice', b.Id as 'SaleDetailId', (Select Min(x.Id) From SaleDetailModels x Where x.SaleId = a.Id) as 'MinSaleDetailId' From SaleModels a, SaleDetailModels b, ProductModels d, ProductTypes e Where a.Id = b.SaleId and b.ProductId = d.Id and d.ProductTypeId = e.Id and a.CustomerName Like '" + cbx + "' and a.SaleDate between '" + FromDate + "' and '" + ToDate + "' Order by Id, SaleDetailId";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds, "FullSale");
            con.Close();

bin.Debug.Reports.rptFullSale objRpt = new bin.Debug.Reports.rptFullSale();
                objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["FullSale"]);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
                crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

What i check it runs till connection close "con.Close()". after that it can not update the report. cbx, fromdate and todate are basically combobox and datetimepickers on the reportform. It also can not take up the fields data as well so i use a static data pass using delegate, not the actual data on the reportform.

The two open forms are like this [image]

Thanks in advance. Waiting any positive reply

Regards

Comment: `Reports.FullSaleReport saleReport = (Reports.FullSaleReport)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Reports.FullSaleReport));`This creates a _new_ Report Window. I thought you wanted to update the already opened one?

Comment: Secondly, is it possible to have more than 1 ReportWindow opened? If so, the condition will be false (because == 1, better use >= 1 and update all?). Is there a special reason you are using delegates and not events?

Comment: yes i want to update the opened one. what i have to do?

Comment: Probably unrelated: Don't concat sql strings, use SqlParameters, and I'd use a `using` block there.

Comment: yes it is possible that more than 1 report windows opened but not the same form. Different report windows.

Comment: _"what i have to do?"_ Do a foreach over the filtered FormCollection and call the items' `ShowReport` function.

Comment: where i concat sql string

Comment: sql query runs but don't update the report using delegate method. Preview button runs the same query and update the report

Comment: foreach loop? Why?

Comment: `String Query = "..."+ fromDate + ".." + toDate + "... ";` <- here. Have a look at the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataAdapter__ctor_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_

Comment: "foreach loop? Why?" Don't you want all Forms updated? Or only a specific one? Then it gets tricky.

Comment: But anyway: What I'd do is that I'd have a Checkbox on the ReportForms that switches "Watch updates" on or off. Then have the main form fire an event on db updates. Have the ReportForms register for that event and in the handler , if the checkbox is set, trigger that very same update that you are doing on pressing the "update" button.

Comment: Only one form. Not all forms. I only want to update reportform after inserting a data into database through mainform

Comment: OK, but you said, there can be more than 1 open at any given time. So how would you identify that one?

Comment: leave that. its bit confusing. in simple words i only want to update reportform when data is inserted into database through mainform. Both forms are opened at the same time. Let us suppose there is no other form in the application. I update my question using a picture

Comment: OK. Try: `if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Reports.FullSaleReport>().Count() == 1)
                {
                    Application.OpenForms.OfType<Reports.FullSaleReport>().FirstOrDefault()?.ShowReport("%", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString());
                }` If it works, I'll explain further.

Comment: nothing happened.

Comment: reportform not updated at all.

Comment: Ok, that's odd. I'll have another look.

Comment: Where is CrystalReportViewer from? Is it "CrystalDecisions.Web (CrystalDecisions.Web.dll)"?

Comment: Fildor it updates a report to an empty report. Before it doesn't change report view.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have changed some code to check something so that i told you wrong. but when i rollback the code. it shows an empty report. means update the report view with an empty report.

Comment: Your above mentioned code somehow works for me.

Comment: Just that it updates to an empty report. But that may be a different problem.

Comment: Before this code it couldn't update the report. But now it changes the view although to an empty report. No data has shown on the report

Comment: Fildor Thanks a lot. It works with few more changes

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Highly appreciated. I have to talk to you 4 days before. I have waste my 4 to 5 days on this issue

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199795/discussion-on-question-by-zubair-hasan-delegate-call-can-not-update-already-open).

Answer (score 1):

Since it worked halfway, I'll explain here a bit more detailed:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Reports.FullSaleReport>().Count() == 1) 
{
   Application.OpenForms.OfType<Reports.FullSaleReport>() // List of Forms of Type FullSaleReport
 //vv Return the first entry in the list 
 //|  (which should be always the one we already checked to be there
 //|                v If not null ...
 //|                | vv Call ShowReport Method on the returned instance.
   .FirstOrDefault()?.ShowReport("%",
                                 DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToShortDateString(),
                                 DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()); 
}
```

Comment: I use overloaded showreport() method. The one with 3 parameters and other one empty. I basically wanted to run the empty one but because of testing purpose, I was testing 3 parameters function. Now using your code with empty parameters resolve my problem.

Comment: One thing i can't understand. Why use firstorDefault(). what about tolist()?

Comment: `ToList()` , yes you could. But then you'd need to do `[0]` to get to the element. `FirstOrDefault` gives you the first element right away (if there is one). Since we already know, there has to be one, we could have also used `First()` or `Single`. The point is that we want the instance that is in that collection.

Comment: BTW: A cool way on SO to say "thanks, it helped" is to upvote and if it solved the problem accept the answer ;)